# Textures not loading properly

Tags: technical-issues, pubg-battlegrounds

While playing PUBG the textures are not fully loaded and everything looks blurry; not only at the time of landing but during the entire match. Although very rarely in a few games the textures have been loaded properly and things became clear.
It happened only twice or thrice. I use a Lenovo Zuk Z2 plus (4gb Ram, SD 820). What can I do?

I tried lowering the graphics and force rendering GPU but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you Verified the game files or reinstalled?

Comment: Yes but nothing happened

Comment: I assume the game streams its assets in order to keep CPU/GPU load low, so it could be limited by your hardware (and not your settings). I doubt the textures are missing.

Comment: But textures were fully loaded a few times and everything was clear

Comment: Can you try lowering the draw distance? It could be related to the amount of assets it's loading simultaneously.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to some of the comments on this, it appears to be the mobile Android version of PUBG. Despite the Snapdragon 820 and 4GB of RAM, you need to consider that you have an old phone at this point (in terms of how far technology has come since the Lenovo Zuk Z2+ released in 2016). It's entirely possible that you are expecting too much out of your phone. The Adreno 530 in that phone is a chip designed with 2015 tech in mind, and although 5 years doesn't seem like a lot of time, it is in terms of phone power.

PUBG is a big, intense game, with a lot of assets to load, and a lot of player connections (~100) to handle. It's very possible that what you're experiencing is just how it is for your model phone. Something newer might be a better answer, and I doubt there's a technical fix that will drastically improve your gameplay experience.

Comment: But as I said above textures were loaded a few times

Comment: Anecdotal evidence at this point. A few times is not 100% of the time, so it really doesn't mean much, I'm sorry.